# Django model field having multiple dictionary options

Tags: django, django-models

I am running into an issue and this is a replica in a smaller scale of what I am running into..

```
class Garage(models.Model):
    vehicles = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What I want to store in my garage is multiple vehicles. And I want each vehicle to be a Make and Model.

So I was thinking I could do something like this..

```
class Make(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField()

class Model(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField()
```

Then I can specify in my `Garage` class any amount of Make:Model objects and assign them to the vehicles field.

So then essentially, vehicles would like like:

```
{'Ford':'Mustang', 'Chevrolet':'Camaro', 'Dodge':'Charger'}
```

**Edit**:

In my admin panel I want to be able to create multiple garages. When I go to a garage I want to be able to see a new field for each Make. And then for each make I want it to be a multiselect field for all of the models.

```
Ford: [Mustang, Camaro, Charger]
Chevy: [Mustang, Camaro, Charger]
Dodge: [Mustang, Camaro, Charger]
```

So then when I reference that Garage, I can see which vehicles I have in it by make and model.

When I go to the admin panel I want the options:

Makes (Where I can create just a list of all the makes)
Models (Where I make a list of all the models)
Garage (Where it displays all of the Makes with a multiselect next to each make displaying all the models).

Then when I save that Garage is now updated with those vehicles.

Comment: It sounds like you need a `Vehicle` model with a foreign key to `Garage`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a Vehicle model that you're going to add into your garage model. So, I suggest you to do the following:

```py
class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class CarMake(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    make = models.ForeignKey(CarMake)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)
    garage = models.ForeignKey(
        Garage, related_name='vehicles',
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

And you can register your models in the `admin.py` file:

```py
class VehicleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Vehicle

class GarageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Garage
    inlines = (VehicleInline,)

admin.site.register(CarMake)
admin.site.register(CarModel)
admin.site.register(Vehicle)
admin.site.register(Garage, GarageAdmin)
```

Comment: I should be able to create just a large list of Makes and a large list of Models. Then when I go to Vehicle in the admin panel I should see a new option for each Make that I have created. Then for each make I should be given a multiselect field to select any models that I want.

Comment: @Halloween You can do that by using inline models into your Vehicle.

Comment: I am not familiar with inline models. Do you have a quick example?

Comment: Are you allowing a vehicle to have multiple models? why a multiselect?

Comment: I want the garage to have multiple vehicles. And each make have multiple models.

Comment: @Halloween I edited the answer, from that point I think you can achieve what you're seeking

Comment: Could you come into chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214136/django

Comment: I reckon there should be a intermediate table between Vehicle and Garage, so that Vehicle does not worry about the garage attribute. Applying OO concept.

Comment: @JamesLin Intermediate tables only make sense for many-to-many relations, while a one-to-many relation is needed for this case. The answer is correct.